# WCF handle update to person object

Tags: wcf, web

I have this pretty common problem. I have POCO person class.

```
 [DataContract]
public class Person
{
 [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
 public int id{get;set;}

 [DataMember]
 public decimal? Age{get;set;}

 [DataMember]
 public decimal? NumberOfChildren{get;set;}
}
```

I have WCF operation which is this

```
public class PersonManagerService
{    public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
    //performs sql to update person in db
    }
}
```

3) Now imagine that in the database there is a person record with id=1, NumberOfChildren=5 and Age=15.

imagine i have client code like this in which case i **only want to update the age of the person and leave all other fields as is**.

```
  Person p = new Person{id=1,Age=26;}
   PersonManagerService service=new PersonManagerService();
   service.UpdatePerson(p);
```

Now once this code runs the problem that i will have is that the sql statment will run and will update the NumberOfChildren to NULL. Now i know i can add null checking to prevent this which is straightforward. However what i want is that in the case where i do specify the field to have a null value then the update should set to null value, if not set then do nothing with that field. So what i am thinking is that i will need to do something like this. Create an update person object which has this

```
   [DataContract]
    public class UpdatePerson
    {
     [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
     public int id{get;set;}

     public bool IsAgeSpecified{get;set;}

     [DataMember]
     public decimal? Age{get;set;}

     public bool IsNumberOfChildrenSpecified{get;set;}

     [DataMember]
     public decimal? NumberOfChildren{get;set;}
    }
```

Client code will be this now

```
   UpdatePerson p = new UpdatePerson{id=1,IsAgeSpecified=true,Age=26;}
   PersonManagerService service=new PersonManagerService();
   service.UpdatePerson(p);
```

I know that this will work but i dont really like the approach as you are now dealing with an updatePerson rather than a Person. has anyone any suggestions to a better approach?

Comment: What drives the requirement for partial update? Are age/children optional or are unknown at the time of entry and will be known later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm.. your service should expose only the data that will be used by the client. This amount of data then would be updated all together. Not sure if this is applicable in your scenario, but I was wondering if you should consider to divide your service to make it more oriented to the client needs.

For instance, you could consider to divide a "Person" into presentation classes oriented to what the service really updates. But since "Person" is already too small, in this particular scenario maybe you can open the properties into parameters that should be updated together. You could get something like this:

```
public class PersonManagerService
{    public void UpdatePerson(int personId, decimal age, decimal numberOfChildren);
    {
        //Instantiate new Person object filling the properties, say that age and numberOfChilren properties must be updated and call _UpdatePerson.
    }

    public void UpdatePerson(int personId, decimal age)
    {
        //Instantiate new Person object filling the age, say that age property must be updated and call _UpdatePerson.
    }

    public void UpdatePerson(decimal numberOfChildren, int personId)
    {
        //Instantiate new Person object filling the numberOfChildren, say that numberOfChilren property must be updated and call _UpdatePerson.
    }
    private void _UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
          //do db stuffs
    }
}
```

To say which properties should be updated, you could do something like `context.Entry(youreEntity).Property(e => e.SomeProperty).IsModified = true` (doing this, I think you don't need to attach the entity)

Be aware that this approach can lack in scalability. You can also group parameters that should be updated together in specific class.

Does this approach works for your needs?

Comment: Just for the record, I saw the code to update specific properties [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115406/exclude-column-from-being-updateable-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a step which is to identify a person.  Where do you come up with id = 1?

For example:

```
   PersonManagerService service=new PersonManagerService();
   Person p = service.findPersonByNumberOfChildren(5);
   p.Age = 26;
   service.UpdatePerson(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make your class "UpdatePerson" inherit from "Person".  This way you don't have to code the definition of "Person" twice.  You still have to to do the mapping.  Not sure if you use AutoMapper or something similar, or you just write the mapping manually.

```
[DataContract]
    public class UpdatePerson : Person
    {

     [DataMember]
     public bool IsAgeSpecified{get;set;}

     [DataMember]
     public bool IsNumberOfChildrenSpecified{get;set;}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflection and have a method that like

```
    UpdatePropertiesofPerson(Person personTobeUpdated, List<string> listOfPropertiesToBeUpdated)
    {
         foreach (var propertyName in listOfPropertiesToBeUpdated)
         {
           var propertyValue = personTobeUpdated.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(personTobeUpdated, null);

           //sql update statement here using the propertyName and the value
         }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now once this code runs the problem that i will have is that the sql statment will run and will update the NumberOfChildren to NULL.

You could modify your stored procedure to handle that scenario by making that select from the existing row and then comparing with what is sent from the Middle tier. This way your stored procedure would also run better because there would be less of parameter sniffing.

```
Create Procedure UpdatePerson
  InputAge int, NumChildren int, Identifier int
   Begin
      Declare @NoOfChildrenCount Int
      Declare @Age Int

      Select @NoOfChildrenCount= NoOfChildren, @Age= Age from Person where Id = Identifier
      If InputAge <> @Age
        set  @Age = InputAge
      If NumChildren <> @NoOfChildrenCount
        set @NoOfChildrenCount = NumberChildren 

      Update Person Set Age = @Age , NoOfChildren=@NoOfChildrenCount where Id = Identifier
End
```